# Get current URL and add something in front with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a multi-language website, I want two buttons for the two languages that exist on the website.

The standard url would be: mydomain.com/something (this would be in german for example)
 The english url for this is: mydomain.com/en/something

How can I set up the buttons to get the current url/ page (in this case `/something` and  add `/en` in front of it? Everything I found was to add stuff after the full domain.

Thank you very much.

Comment: In your js you can use `window.location` to get the url etc

Answer (score 1):

check [Location Obj MDM docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)

```
console.log(document.location.origin + "/en" + document.location.pathname)
```

Comment: Instead of document.location.host use document.location.origin + `/${lang_code}` + document.location.pathname

Comment: Thanks. Now I just have to apply it somehow to buttons, but in general it's working

Comment: @KrishnaDevashish yep. its better solution. the .host can contain port number.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your end goal is but if it involves reloading the same page with the localisation in the URL (i.e. on button click the page reloads and the page's URL is changed to **mydomain.com/en/something** meaning that on your next button click, the page would need to reload and its URL would need to be **mydomain.com/something** again) then you may need to look into RegEx and running it against the current URL to then swap out the URLs in the button so that on click you go to the correct version of the domain.

If the end goal is to only get the current URL and toggle whether the localisation appears in the URL or not then take a look at the snippet below which should hopefully help you out a bit.

For some further reading, I think these resources may be helpful for you:

- **RegEx:** [Regular expressions guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)
- **RegEx**: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) - this is essentially a playground for practicing and testing your RegEx.
- **Location Object**: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) or [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $languageToggle = $('#language-toggle');
  var origin = location.origin;
  var pathname = location.pathname;

  $languageToggle.on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var toLanguage = $this.data('to-language');
    var currentLanguage = $this.data('current-language');
    var localisation = '';

    /**
     * This if statement will help prevent the constructedUrl variable
     * from ever having a url such as https://website.com//page
     * (notice the double forward slashes after .com).
     */
    if (toLanguage) {
      localisation = '/' + toLanguage;
    }

    var constructedUrl = origin + localisation + pathname;

    $this.data('to-language', currentLanguage);
    $this.data('current-language', toLanguage);

    $('#output').text(constructedUrl);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output">Click on the toggle button</div>

<button id="language-toggle" data-to-language="en" data-current-language="">
  Toggle language
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. But why should this be a problem? There would be always two buttons to switch between languages. It's not meant to be toggle. One button for `german` one for `english`. The one the user is currently at would be somehow visualised to show what language is currently shown. The only problem I can think of is, when the user is on the `/en` page and clicks the `english` button again. Then he would end up on `mydomain.com/en/en/something`

Comment: Ah I see, yes you did mentions "button" not "button" so my bad. In which case, if you always have two buttons, then maybe something like [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0vgcu9od/1/) might help.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var myFunc = () => {
  window.location.href = window.location.href + "place you text here"
}
```

```html
Click the button and the page will be edited
<button onclick="myFunc()">click me</button>
```

Comment: Well, thats adding the `place your text here` behind the url. Thats what I especially don' want.

Comment: Search in the `window.location` object, it separates the URL for you